# почему не работает top and left у элемента?

Tags: html, css

```css
#general {
  height: 5797px;
}

#header1 {
  background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1366px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.5577%;
}

#picture1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5.6716%;
  left: 7.1742%;
}

.nav1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 6.7164%;
  left: 47.73%;
}
```

```html
<div id="general">
  <header id="header1">
    <img src="01_one_page.png" id="picture1">
    <nav class="nav1">
      <a href="#">home</a>
      <a href="#">about</a>
      <a href="#">work</a>
      <a href="#">process</a>
      <a href="#">services</a>
      <a href="#">testimonials</a>
      <a href="#">contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

почему не работает top и left у #picture? top и left работает только у .nav1

Comment: Проверяй не только в хроме :)

Comment: эта жесть будет работать только у вас ..на другом разрешении экрана будет выглядеть иначе ...у вас экран 1376 или какое то другое а у меня 24" это уже другое и эта жесть с процентами после точки не заметна вообще ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в хроме. Есть [соответствующий баг](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=778366&q=css%20top%20percentage&can=2) еще с 2017 года, но продвижения по нему нет.

Суть бага: неправильно рендерится `inline` или `inline-block` элемент с позицией `relative`, у которого значение `top` указано в процентах.

Для решения можно поменять значение свойства `display` на `block`:

```css
#general {
  height: 5797px;
}

#header1 {
  background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1366px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.5577%;
}

#picture1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 7.1742%;
  display: block;
}

.nav1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  left: 47.73%;
}
```

```html
<div id="general">
  <header id="header1">
    <img src="01_one_page.png" id="picture1">
    <nav class="nav1">
      <a href="#">home</a>
      <a href="#">about</a>
      <a href="#">work</a>
      <a href="#">process</a>
      <a href="#">services</a>
      <a href="#">testimonials</a>
      <a href="#">contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: за какие прегрешения вы изменили мои проценты top у #picture и top у .nav? Это спасает ситуацию? Это улучшает картинку? Я же perfect-pixel верстаю, господи

Comment: @Степан, :-D просто для теста удобнее круглые значения были :)

Answer (score 3):

Заменить у элементов `#picture1` и `.nav1` способ позиционирования `position: relative;` на `position: absolute;`

```css
#general {
  height: 5797px;
}

#header1 {
  background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1366px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.5577%;
}

#picture1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5.6716%;
  left: 7.1742%;
}

.nav1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.7164%;
  left: 47.73%;
}
```

```html
<div id="general">
  <header id="header1">
    <img src="01_one_page.png" id="picture1">
    <nav class="nav1">
      <a href="#">home</a>
      <a href="#">about</a>
      <a href="#">work</a>
      <a href="#">process</a>
      <a href="#">services</a>
      <a href="#">testimonials</a>
      <a href="#">contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```